# Flex : How to start a flex/air app by dragging a file to the application Icon and got the file

Tags: apache-flex, air, icons, drag

I'm building a flex application

It has a functionality that can upload files to server

The customer will want to open app by dragging file to the icon and the app will start and begin  uploading. But I cannot find how to implement that

Can anyone help me? Any help or link will be great appreciated.

Edit: thanks to alxx

Here is my code

```
private function initComponents():void {
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);
}

public function onInvokeEvent(invocation:InvokeEvent):void {
    arguments = invocation.arguments;
    currentDir = invocation.currentDirectory;
    if(arguments.length > 0)
    {
        var dfile:File = new File(arguments[0]);
        if(dfile.exists) {
        if(ArrayUtil.getItemIndex(dfile.extension,ConfigManager.AllSupportedFileExtensions) > -1)
            uploadQueue.push(dfile);
            if(!logged)
                Alert.show("Please login before upload");

        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listen to InvokeEvent.INVOKE of Application, as described [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_launch_1.html#1038002). You'll get full native path to dropped file in arguments array (just tested it myself.)